# RAM Timing: Is CAS Latency in READ command same as WRITE command?

Tags: memory, timing, memory-timings

As far as I know and according to wikipedia about CAS Latency:

> CL is the delay time between the moment a memory controller tells the
>   memory module to access a particular memory column on a RAM module,
>   and the moment the data from the given array location is available on
>   the module's **output** pins.

So the definition above is about *Read* command which is sent from memory controller and ram module, returns the stored data on its output data. But what about *Write* command? is CAS Latency same? or memory timing about writing is completely different from reading?